# Perl: Specify Encode flags like FB_PERLQQ to open() or binmode()

Tags: perl, character-encoding

Is there a way to make auto-encoding file handles use specified `Encode` flags?

Specifically I want to make STDOUT and STDERR use the Encode::FB_PERLQQ flag so any characters which can not be encoded are output as \x{ABCD} instead of garbage + a nasty warning message.

More specifically, I want to `use open ':locale'` to auto-detect whatever encoding the environment expects, and modify STDOUT & STDERR to use that encoding but with the flag `Encode::FB_PERLQQ` in effect.   I imagine doing something like

```
use open ':locale';  # determine what the environment expects
my @layers = PerlIO::get_layers(*STDOUT);
my ($encoding) = ("@layers" =~ /encoding\((.*?)\)/);
binmode(*STDOUT, "something which means $encoding with flags Encode::FB_PERLQQ")
```

My application is Perl module test cases, which are automatically run on many smoker machines all over the internet, including some Windows hosts using the cp850 character set.  If I just make test scripts encode to UTF-8 then on those machines some characters appear as garbage; I would rather see the \x{...} fallback enabled by FB_PERLQQ so the code-point could be determined from the logs.

Comment: See https://metacpan.org/pod/PerlIO::encoding